# How to set up an Eclipse P2 server using Google Sites?

Tags: eclipse, p2, google-sites

I'm trying to use Google Sites to host an Eclipse P2 site.

However, Install New Software fails to the site because the features and plugins directories are not found.  It seems that Google Sites only simulates subdirectories on FileCabinet pages.

Is there an alternative Google Sites approach?

Or is there a way to set up a P2 site without subdirectories or so that Install New Software will reference a zip file?

Any alternative recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using the space of google code to host my p2 repository. It works well.

Comment: Thanks Kane.  How did you set up google code?  I put my Eclipse site there, but it still isn't found by Eclipse's Install New Software.  http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/mobile-web-development-with-phonegap/source/browse/#svn/trunk/mds11.site

Comment: @PaulB, You don't find the correct url. Try http://svn.codespot.com/a/eclipselabs.org/mobile-web-development-with-phonegap/trunk/mds11.site/

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess...perhaps some of your files are read-only.